# texture(...) via textureoffset(...) performance in glsl

Tags: opengl, glsl, texture-mapping, glsles

Does utilizing `textureOffset(...)` increase performance compared to calculating offsets manually and using regular `texture(...)` function?

As there is a GL_MAX_PROGRAM_TEXEL_OFFSET property, I would guess that it can fetch offseted texels in a single, or at least as few as possible, fetches making it superb for example blurring effects, but I cant seem to find out how it works internally anywhere?

*Update:*
Reformulating question: is it common among gl-drivers to make any optimizations regarding texture fetches when utilizing the textureOffset(...) function?

Answer (score 2):

You're asking the wrong question. The question should not be whether the more specific function will always have better performance. The question is whether the more specific function will ever be *slower*.

And there's no reason to expect it to be slower. If the hardware has no specialized functionality for offset texture accesses, then the compiler will just offset the texture coordinate manually, exactly like you could. If there is hardware to help, then it will use it.

So if you have need of `textureOffset`s and can live within its limitations, there's no reason *not* to use it.

> I would guess that it can fetch offseted texels in a single, or at least as few as possible, fetches making it superb for example blurring effects

No, that's `textureGather`. `textureOffset` is for doing exactly what its name says: accessing a texture based on a texture coordinate, with an texel offset from that coordinate's location.

`textueGather` samples from multiple neighboring texels all at once. If you need to read a section of a texture to do bluring, `textureGather` (and `textureGatherOffset`) are going to be more useful than `textureOffset`.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question, I'm aware of textureGather, what I wanted to know is if there are any drivers, or even common, which can utilize textureOffset for fetching multiple texels in behind.